# How can we compute a binomial series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {-{3}/{2} \choose n}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients

I have been trying to find problems involving binomial series and then converting the series into an integral, but this particular series, 
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {-{3}/{2} \choose n}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$$
has stumped me. My initial approach was showing that 
$$S = \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2{x}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}\ \mathrm{d}x$$ which I am not sure how to solve. An easier case would be if we had $-\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $-\frac{1}{3}$. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Concerning the evaluation of
$$
S = \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2{x}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}\ \mathrm{d}x
$$ one may recall the [Euler beta result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$
\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\ \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)},\quad a>0,\,b>0,
$$ giving with $t=x^2$, $\,dt=2xdx$,
$$
2\int_0^1 x^{2a-1}(1-x^2)^{-1/3}\ \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{\Gamma\left(a+\frac23\right)},\quad a>0,
$$ then by differentiating twice one gets
$$
S = \left.\partial_a^2\left(\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)}{8\Gamma\left(a+\frac23\right)}\right)\right|_{a=\frac12}
$$
a result which one may simplify in terms of the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).